# Difference between ParseUser.getCurrentUser.getList("isFollowing").add(users.get(p)) and ParseUser.getCurrentUser.add("isFollowing", users.get(p))

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parse-platform, parse-dashboard

I am making a simple twitter like app where a user can follow or post.

I am using parse android for this.

In the users table I have created a column called "isFollowing" which indicates name of followers.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CheckedTextView checkedTextView=(CheckedTextView)view;
                if (checkedTextView.isChecked()){
                    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isFollowing").add(users.get(position));
                }else {
                    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isFollowing").remove(users.get(position));
                }
                ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
            }
        });
```

The `users` arrayList contains the number of users present. If we click on list view then the name of the user will be added into `isFollowing` array in the parse database.

I am using `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isFollowing").add(users.get(position));` to add the username to my array which is giving me a null pointer exception.

But if I use `ParseUser.getCurrentUser.add("isFollowing", users.get(position))`, then it is getting executed correctly.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably in the first moment your list is not initialize, so `getList("isFollowing")` return null. Are you setting an empty `[]` array when creating this user to this field?

Also, if you expect this array to grow over time and in some cases hit > 20 items, you can have performance problems in the future. I'd use relation or pointer fields to store this kind of data.

Comment: I didn't understand,  _The other way will probably only change the list that you have in the scope but not actually the parse object array._

Comment: Can you answer this too, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65312284/parseuser-getlist-in-parse-database

Comment: I've checked the SDK code and `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isFollowing").add(users.get(position))` should also worked but you have to make sure that the isFollowing field of the user is initialized with at least an empty array beforehand. I edited the answer.