# ParseUser.getList() in parse database

Tags: android, arraylist, parse-platform, parse-dashboard

I am creating a twitter like app where we can follow other users and read their tweets.

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isFollowing").remove(users.get(position));
List<String> tmpUsers=ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isFollowing");
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().remove("isFollowing");
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("isFollowing", tmpUsers);
```

The above code runs when user wants to unfollow.

I had a doubt in:

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isFollowing").remove(users.get(position));
List<String> tmpUsers=ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isFollowing");
```

when we are using `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isFollowing").remove(users.get(position));`
are we downloading the list from the database and removing the element locally?

When we run `List<String> tmpUsers=ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isFollowing");` are we downloading the list again or are we getting the list which has `users.get(position)` removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not "downloading" the list in any of these lines. You are accessing the list that is already cached in your device. In order to fetch the latest data you need to use:

```java
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().fetch();
```